# Control+C handling in multithread perl script

Tags: multithreading, perl, unix, keyboardinterrupt

I'm new in perl and I have a problem with handling ^C in my perl script. When I'm trying to continue script execution after recieving ^C during the sleep I have only output before $FLAG = 2; and nothing after:

```
# perl test.pl 
sleeping...
^Cawaiking...  =  
#
```

instead of:

```
# perl test.pl 
sleeping...
awaiking...    ====                                              
some..
#
```

It seams that ^C is killing the progres bar thread and after it dies no actions but print could be performed in the main thread. Could anyone help me with this problem?

```
$SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';
our $FLAG : shared = 1; 
...
sub call1{
    $FLAG = 1;
    my $pBar = threads->new(\&progressBarInit);
    $pBar->detach;
    print "sleeping...\n";
    sleep 5;
    print "awaiking...\n";
    $FLAG = 2;
    print "some..\n";
    return @result;
}

call1();

sub progressBarInit{
my $max = 50;
    my $counter = 1;
    while($FLAG == 1){
        progressBar( $counter, $max, 50, '=' );
        $counter++;
        if($counter > $max){$counter=1;}
        sleep 1;
    }
}

sub progressBar {
    my ( $counter, $max, $width, $char ) = @_;
    local $| = 1;
    printf "               %-${width}s\r", $char x (($width-1)*$counter/$max);
}
```

Comment: This code on Windows works fine. Any `^C` is ignored.

Comment: Maybe [these warnings](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=718) may help, using `syswrite` instead of `printf` in `progressBar`?

Comment: @ring0, but the signal handler isn't calling progressBar. I don't see how it would apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you setup the signal handler in the parent.

According to this: http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

> Signal handlers need to be set up in the threads for the signals they are expected to act upon. Here's an example for cancelling a thread:

Instead of using a flag you could use signals to communicate:

```
sub progressBarInit    {
  # Thread 'cancellation' signal handler
  $SIG{'KILL'} = sub { threads->exit(); };
  $SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';
  ...
}
...
# Signal the thread to terminate, and then detach
# it so that it will get cleaned up automatically
   my $pBar = threads->new(\&progressBarInit);    
    print "sleeping...\n";
    sleep 5;
    print "awaiking...\n";
    $pBar->kill('KILL')->detach();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. If I place $SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE'; in to the progressBarInit instead of the beginning of the script it simply terminate it when ^C is pressed. (All changes you have mentioned was applied).